# Additional invocation phrases disappear from Actions Console

Tags: google-smart-home

I am trying to add Additional invocation phrases on the Directory Information tab for a Smart Action on the Actions Console. After filling phrases in and pressing the Save button I receive a notification "Assistant app information saved successfully". But filled in phrases do not appear in the list under Additional invocation phrases. Also, I cannot see filled in phrases in the "Explore all actions" -> "What it can do" tab of Google Assistant for the Smart Action. I can find there only auto-generated phrases.

I've tried to fill in phrases with and without Action name or Device name, but nothing worked.

How can I add Additional invocation phrases to Smart Action? Auto-generated phrases partially don't match the functionality of my Action.

Comment: is this for a smart home action?

Comment: @proppy yes, this is for a smart home action

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot see filled in phrases in the "Explore all actions" -> "What it can do" tab of Google Assistant for the Smart Action. I can find there only auto-generated phrases.

This functionality is not currently supported for smart home Actions. Example invocations on the "Explore" pages are auto-generated from the device type/trait information provided by your fulfillment. Feel free to log this as a feature request in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148).

> Auto-generated phrases partially don't match the functionality of my Action.

If there is a concern here, you can file an issue on the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) with your agent (project) id and we can forward it to the certification team for review.